# How to convert from IFC file to indoorGML?

Tags: ifc, fme

I have 3D building model in IFC format with LOD2.

I'm trying to covert that model into indoorGML format using FME Desktop,it's exported empty XML.

Please if any have the template share with me as well idea or suggestions also......

Answer (score 0):

IndoorGML is a standard used for mapping building interiors. Depending on the quality/LOD-level of your IFC building model, there may be no results if the interior elements are missing, or if they are not specific elements that FME Desktop is looking for (e.g. IfcDoor, IfcWindow). A generic element type like IfcBuildingElementProxy will yield poor results.